# Limit of series as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Hello can somebody help me find the limit of this sequence I have as homework ? I tried several methods but I can't find the answer.

$$x_n = \sqrt{n+3} + 2\sqrt{n+2} - 3\sqrt{n+1}$$

So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n =?$

Comment: Series $\neq$ sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b}=\dfrac{n+a-(n+b)}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}}=?$$

$$\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+2}+3(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+1})+2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})$$ and the limit can be decomposed in two terms.

Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}}=0.$$